# The Windows SDK sample (Namespace Extension) does not run correctly on Windows 11

Tags: c++, windows-11, shell-namespace-extension

I want to implement a Namespace Extension and custom column filtering.

[image: WindowsExplorerColumnCategory]

I tried to run this sample from Windows SDK 7.1, in Windows 11:

[ExplorerDataProvider](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/shellextensibility/explorerdataprovider)

This sample implements a Shell Namespace Extension including custom categorizers.

I made some changes to fix the missing `IID_IItemCategorizer` and an Access Violation when `LoadString()` is called.

I debugged the code of `Category.cpp` and I realized that all expected functions are not being called.

The functions should be run in below sequence:

1. `CFolderViewImplCategoryProvider::GetCategoryForSCID`
2. `CFolderViewImplCategoryProvider::CreateCategory`
3. `CFolderViewImplCategorizer_Name::GetCategory`
4. `CFolderViewImplCategorizer_Name::GetCategoryInfo`

But, after successfully running the first 3 functions, `GetCategoryInfo()` is not being called.

Is it because of Windows 11? Is the SDK not updated? Or did I make a mistake? How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you register the DLL as indicated in the readme? `Type "regsvr32.exe ExplorerDataProvider.dll" at the command line.
If you run this command from an elevated command prompt, the self-registration will also register the .propdesc file automatically. If it is run from a non-elevated command prompt then the namespace extension will still work but without custom property functionality.`

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes. The Extension works, except for this part.

Comment: Did you try running it on Windows 10 (perhaps in a VM) to see if it works there?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Do you have expected definition for IID_IItemCategorizer? can you share it?